# React Hooks Issue with state getting reset

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to develop a Tic Tac Toe game using React and am stuck at the basic step i.e. I want the first move to be X and flip the next one to O and so-on.

I have the below code. So, I try to initialize state "data" (what is to be set) initially to X and then set the state "nextChoice" to be the reverse via:

```
nxtChoice = (data === "X") ? "O" : "X";
setNextChoice(nxtChoice);
```

Now, it seems like the issue is that the Square component gets re-mounted again and then the "firstMove" state gets set to true every time causing the issue i.e. not able to flip between X and O.

What is the logical issue with above code and how can I not reset firstMove every time?

```
function Square(props) {
  const [firstMove, setFirstMove] = useState(true);
  let [nextChoice, setNextChoice] = React.useState("X");
  let [data, setData] = React.useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data !== "") {
      nxtChoice = (data === "X") ? "O" : "X";
      setNextChoice(nxtChoice);
    }
  }, [data]);

  const squareClicked = () => {
    let nxtChoice = firstMove ? "X" : nextChoice;
    setData(nxtChoice);
    setFirstMove(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="square" style={squareStyle} onClick={squareClicked}>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={containerStyle} className="gameBoard">
        <div id="statusArea" className="status" style={instructionsStyle}>
          Next player: <span>X</span>
        </div>
        <div id="winnerArea" className="winner" style={instructionsStyle}>
          Winner: <span>None</span>
        </div>
        <button style={buttonStyle}>Reset</button>
        <div style={boardStyle}>
          <div className="board-row" style={rowStyle}>
            <Square row={"1"} column={"1"} />
            <Square row={"1"} column={"2"} />
            <Square row={"1"} column={"3"} />
          </div>
          <div className="board-row" style={rowStyle}>
            <Square row={"2"} column={"1"} />
            <Square row={"2"} column={"2"} />
            <Square row={"2"} column={"3"} />
          </div>
          <div className="board-row" style={rowStyle}>
            <Square row={"3"} column={"1"} />
            <Square row={"3"} column={"2"} />
            <Square row={"3"} column={"3"} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code can also be seen on
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-glade-c1ssw?file=/src/App.js:1307-3349

Comment: You notice that some of the variables in your example are not defined, maybe you should fix the lint errors beforehand

Comment: yes, plan to do that during refactoring the entire code...

Answer (score 0):

What you see happening is not the `Square` component is remounted, but for every instance of `Square`, it has a separate individually working state.

In order for the game to work those states should be moved to the `Board` component and passed to each of the `Square` components.

Comment: So should the thought process be like the state should always be at the topmost of the hierarchy and flow down to child components...something like DDAU ?

Any justification or reasoning for the same would be really helpful...

Comment: If you want your components to share that single source of information, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems...

The main one being that the state of the game is stored within the squares instead of within the app component.